# Is it possible to nest an extension method inside another one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, extension-methods

Say I want to write an extension method for `HtmlHelper`. I can do that pretty easily, like so:

```
public static string Capitalize(this HtmlHelper helper, string theString)
{
    return theString.toUpper();
}
```

and call it with `Html.Capitalize("some stuff")`.

What if I want to have a whole bunch of methods that are of a certain type, I want them grouped all together? For example, using our `Capitalize` function, maybe I want `Html.StringUtils` to be a thing, so I could call various related methods like this:

`Html.StringUtils.Capitalize("some stuff")`
`Html.StringUtils.WordsToArray("some stuff")`
`Html.StringUtils.Reverse("some stuff")`
`...`

Is there an easy way to do that? I'm trying to avoid a situation where I have to do `StringUtils.Capitalize()` as its own function, which takes the `HtmlHelper` as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a way to do that directly.  If extension *properties* were supported, you could get that to work, but since the extension method is for `HtmlHelper`, the method name must come directly after an `HtmlHelper` reference (in this case the `Html` property).

Note that you can group the methods themselves in namespaces and/or classes:

```
public static class StringUtils
{
    public static string Capitalize(this HtmlHelper helper, string theString)
    { ...
    }
    public static string WordsToArray(this HtmlHelper helper, string theString)
    { ...
    }
    public static string Reverse(this HtmlHelper helper, string theString)
    { ...
    }
}
```

but the syntax to call them won't reference that:

```
Html.Capitalize("some stuff")
Html.WordsToArray("some stuff")
Html.Reverse("some stuff")
```